# Remove key and value from object

Tags: java, object

My data model is as follow:

```
public class CustomerObject implements Serializable
{
public Integer pkid;
public String code;
public String name;

    public CustomerObject()
{
    pkid = new Integer(0);
    code = "";
            name = "";
    }
}
```

Now I am calling this from another class:

```
public CustomerObject getCustObj() {
    CustomerObject custObj = new CustomerObject();
    custObj.pkid = new Integer(1001);
    custObj.code = "CUST1001";

    return custObj;
}
```

Now here in `getCustObj()` function I want to pass only `pkid` and `code`. I mean I want to remove the variable "`name`" from the object and then pass. So my passing object will look like:

```
    CustomerObject()
    {
        pkid = 1000;
        code = CUST1001;
    }
```

Please help how I can do this.

Actually I have a data model of 200 variable. I will pass this using webservice. But during pass by webservice I may need only 20 to pass. So I want to reduce the data size.

Comment: Why doesn't your `getCustObj` work the way you want?

Comment: Don't assign value to name. By the way, don't make instance variables (fields) public, make them private and provide accessor methods.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new CustomerObject in `getCustObj()`? you are supposed to return the one that constructed with the constructor. Regardless, theres nothign wrong with making a new one in there. You don't actually return anything in that method though, so thats an error. If you don't want name, you can set it to null. If its there in the class definition and you are returning an object of the class, the name variable is going to be there. Don't have it as a member of the class if you don't want it to be returned.

Comment: @Sanchit thanks. I have added the return value in my function. I can't remove name variable from my class because I want to maintain it dynamically. Here I am not passing name, another method will not pass code.

Comment: If you have name in your class. You WILL return it if you return an object of class `CustomerObject`. The simplest solution is to not return an object of CustomerObject but say an object of `CustomerObjectWithoutName` which extends CustomerObject. You will need to make the name variable private though so that it does not get inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Use another constructor in class CustomerObject as following.

```
public class CustomerObject implements Serializable
{
    public Integer pkid;
    public String code;
    public String name;

    public CustomerObject()
    {
        pkid = new Integer(0);
        code = "";
        name = "";
    }
    public CustomerObject(int inPkid, String inCode)
    {
        this.pkid = inPkid;
        code = inCode; 
    }
}
```

When you call getCustomerObject method from another class use as follows

```
public CustomerObject getCustObj() {
    CustomerObject custObj = new CustomerObject(new Integer(1001),"CUST1001");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting name in your object, then it is as good as object not having name because name is null. You can't remove name variable from the object.
But if you really want to do so, you can use inheritance. Make one class with all attributes except name and other class extends the first class and adds name attribute to it. So now you can use first class when you don't need the name attribute.

Comment: Which field I will remove is not fixed. This time I am removing name, may be next time I will not take code. So is there anyway to remove variable dynamically?

Comment: Though I am not sure why you want to do so, but I think you can use decorator pattern here.. Search for "decorator pattern in java" on google...